# SQL Single Byte Double Byte Chinese characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have a table in our Chinese database that stores information as char for some columns.

We would like to convert this to the regular Chinese characters.

How will I achieve this?

Comment: You should describe how the data is currently stored: Which encoding or codepage etc. Since chinese characters definitely exceed the 256 codepoints defined by "char", your data must be encoded *somehow*. If your question means that the current data is Chinese in romanized form (e.g. Pinyin), then there is no way to reliably translate Pinyin into characters.

Comment: The database uses SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation. The column is stored as char. Need chinese simplified.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert those columns to unicode encoding.  I believe Chinese characters are 2 bytes, so hopefully your char field didn't truncate any of the information:

- Create a new column - I'll call it [NVChar1] and the old column [Char1]

  UPDATE tblMyTable
  SET [NVChar1] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [Char1])

[Here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/chinesecharacters/) is an article with more information.

Comment: That did not work. Still getting the same results after I converted it.

Comment: Also, the table is stored in a database with Latin collation.